# How to parallelize the same function using different arguments?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have to fetch JSON from each url which returns children URL(s) and a reward (integer) value. The aim is to traverse the entire tree of URLs and compute the sum of reward values.
My code works but I'm trying to parallelize this. I found out about multiprocessing, but how would I use it to perform the self-defined fetch() function using different URLs at once?

```
def fetch(url):

json_data = requests.get(url).json()

try:
    children = list(json_data['children']) #No duplicate children
    for i in children:
        next_url.append(i)
except:
    print('Tree end')

reward = json_data['reward']
reward_list.append(reward)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem, you want to pass url to the system and have it dynamically feed new urls back into the system as they are discovered. You can do that with a task queue and a list of threads. Feed one url into the queue and the threads will feed the urls they discover for more processing.

```
import threading
import queue

def fetch_worker(url_q, reward_list):
    while True:
        try:
            url = url_q.get()

            # controller requests exit
            if url is None:
                return

            # get url data
            json_data = requests.get(url).json()

            # queue more url_q tasks
            for child in json_data.get('children', []): #No duplicate children
                next_url.append(child)

            # add found reward to list
            reward_list .append(json_data['reward'])
        finally:
            url_q.task_done()


def fetch(url):
    NUM_WORKERS = 10  # just a guess
    reward_list = []
    url_q = queue.Queue()
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=fetch_worker, args=(url_q, reward_list))
        for _ in range(NUM_WORKERS)]
    for t in threads:
        t.start()
    url_q.put(url)
    # wait for url and all subordinate urls to process
    url_q.join()
    # kill the workers
    for _ in range(NUM_WORKERS):
        url_q.put(None)
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
    return reward_list
```

Comment: Exactly. This is exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a url list and want fetch to get reward.
I split the list to buckets and add new loop in fetch

```
def fetch(urls, reward_lst):
    for url in urls:
        json_data = requests.get(url).json()
        try:

            children = list(json_data['children']) 
            for i in children:
                next_url.append(i)
        except:
            print('Tree end')

        reward = json_data['reward']
        reward_lst.append(reward)

def run():
    core_num = mp.cpu_count()
    bucket_size = (len(urls)//core_num) + 1
    reward_lst = mp.Manager().list()
    jobs = []
    for i in range(core_num):
        url_bucket = urls[i*bucket_size,(i+1)*bucket_size]
        p = mp.Process(target=fetch, args=(url_bucket,reward_lst,))
        p.start()
        jobs.append(p)
    [p.join() for p in jobs]
```

Comment: This would work if I had the url list complete, but the url list is being generated dynamically. The idea helped, however. Thanks!